# diplay barchart in a <div>

Tags: dart, chart.js

I try to make this question short, I would like to show the chart in the yellow block, and not below as shown in the screenshot:
[image]

Unfortunatelly I have no idea how to bind the div with the chartobject.

Below is the sorce code:

```dart
<!-- import polymer-element's definition -->
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/paper_elements/paper_button.html">

    <polymer-element name="main-app">
        <template>
            <style>
            </style>

            <div class="bg-container">
                <h1>Chart Demo</h1>

                <div class="bg-container">

                    <div class="chart">
                        **// The chart should be displayed here**
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <paper-button raised class="colored" on-click="{{chartdemo}}">char tdemo</paper-button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </template>
        <script type="application/dart" src="main_app.dart"></script>
    </polymer-element>
```

and the dart file:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:chart/chart.dart';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart' show CustomTag, observable, PolymerElement;

@CustomTag('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {

  MainApp.created() : super.created() {
    Bar bar = new Bar({
        'labels' : ["A","B","C"],
        'datasets' : [
            {
                'fillColor' : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                'strokeColor' : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                'data' : [65,59,90]
            },
        ]

    }, null);

    DivElement container3 = new DivElement();
    container3.style.height ='200px';
    container3.style.width =  '200px';
    document.body.children.add(container3);
    bar.show(container3);
  }

  void chartdemo(Event e, var detail, Node target) {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Don't access the DOM in the constructor of your element. There are lifecycle methods like `ready`, `domReady`, and `attached()` where you can be certain that the DOM is prepared.

```dart
<div id="chartWrapper" class="chart">
  **// The chart should be displayed here**
</div>
```

```dart
@CustomTag('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {

  MainApp.created() : super.created();

  void chartdemo(Event e, var detail, Node target) {

  }

  @override
  void attached() {
    super.attached();
    initChart();
  }

  void initChart() {
    Bar bar = new Bar({
        'labels' : ["A","B","C"],
        'datasets' : [
            {
                'fillColor' : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                'strokeColor' : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                'data' : [65,59,90]
            },
        ]

    }, null);

    DivElement container3 = new DivElement();
    container3.style.height ='200px';
    container3.style.width =  '200px';
    $['chartWrapper'].append(container3);
    bar.show(container3);
  }
}
```

Caution: code not tested

Comment: that worked just great, could you tell me more about attached()?

Comment: Here https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#lifecyclemethods you can find some documentation about Polymer lifecycle methods. This is for JavaScript but it works very similar in Dart. Here on StackOverflow are many Dart examples if it's unclear how to use them and if you're still stuck just ask again ;-)